# How can we determine if these half walls and posts are load bearing?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing

We would like to remove the 2 half walls and posts to open up the room. We opened up the posts and it’s just two 2x4s that are nailed together and drywalled. Would it be safe to assume those are not load bearing and should not affect the structure? I’m including pictures of our blueprints as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is most likely the posts are not load bearing.  If there is no second floor, they are most definitely not load bearing.  If there was a load there would need to be something greater than a couple of 2x4s.  The post were probably just there to help stiffen the 1/2 walls.

Comment: The fact that the posts are lumber doesn't preclude them from supporting a beam or truss girder. Double studs are often used in such cases. The fact that they're not embedded in another wall suggests that they aren't, though.

Comment: Is there another floor above this area so that you can't look at the framing from an attic space? You'll have to repair the drywall around the post tops anyway, so strip a 6" band of drywall off the ceiling around each post. Take an image of each and add the images to your question if you can't figure it out with the drywall stripped.

Comment: Centre walls are suspect for load bearing.  Direction of joists will be helpful, plus what is under(basement supports) those posts.

Comment: This is a 2 story home. The specs state, Triple 3x10 Girder in floor system above. I will try to add a picture of the posts opened up.

Comment: If the posts are under the girder, then a structural engineer should check it it out.  I would imagine they would use 4x4s, but not enough to tell you to remove the double 2x4s.